# Bootstrap HTTPS and IE8

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, https, internet-explorer-8

I am currently working on payment system and we are using bootstrap framework to develop the front end. All the testing is done on local environment and we moved our new project to staging environment and now facing issue on IE8. Layout is not rendering correctly on IE8. there is only 1 different I found between local and staging is the HTTP and HTTPS protocol. Below is my Header section and I am quite sure we have this issue because of the Secure environment. Has anyone had a similar issue ?

```
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
<script src="https://www.example.com/javascript/selectivizr.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://www.example.com/javascript/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/javascript/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>
<link  href="https://www.example.com/css/bootstrap.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<![endif]-->


<link href="https://cdn.example.com/css/index.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://www.example.com/css/index_ie8.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

https://cdn.example.com/css/index.min.css includes Bootstrap CSS + Main CSS

Comment: AFAIK, bootstrap is not fully supported in IE8, in addition, there are a few caveats in using some of bootstrap's elements/javascripts for IE and accessibility, it's your job to make sure you've gone through all of them. Please read this thoroughly http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-browsers
I don't believe this error comes from HTTPS.

Comment: Did you try to remove the first block of code see what happens? removing `selectivizr.min.js`

Comment: @odedta we are gone live with our product details pages (non HTTPS) and working fine with IE8. so the same header section in secure environment has the issues.